# I am having trouble creating array of array with a loop in Golang

Tags: arrays, go

What I am trying to do is create a set of arrays.
I need to get a set of 64 arrays which are mentioned below.
So that I should be able to access each array individually.
I have seen a way to create multiple arrays in a loop in java but not in Go.
I don't want to hard-code  it as I have a function which generates these arrays for different arguments.

```
[11 0 0 0 18 0 0 0]  
[12 0 0 0 19 17 0 0]
[13 9 0 0 20 18 0 0]
[14 10 0 0 21 19 0 0]
[15 11 0 0 22 20 0 0]
[16 12 0 0 23 21 0 0]
[0 13 0 0 24 22 0 0]
[0 14 0 0 0 23 0 0]
[19 0 3 0 26 0 0 0]
[20 0 4 0 27 25 0 0]
[21 17 5 1 28 26 0 0]
[22 18 6 2 29 27 0 0]
[23 19 7 3 30 28 0 0]
[24 20 8 4 31 29 0 0]
[0 21 0 5 32 30 0 0]
[0 22 0 6 0 31 0 0]
[27 0 11 0 34 0 2 0]
[28 0 12 0 35 33 3 1]
[29 25 13 9 36 34 4 2]
[30 26 14 10 37 35 5 3]
[31 27 15 11 38 36 6 4]
[32 28 16 12 39 37 7 5]
[0 29 0 13 40 38 8 6]
[0 30 0 14 0 39 0 7]
[35 0 19 0 42 0 10 0]
[36 0 20 0 43 41 11 9]
[37 33 21 17 44 42 12 10]
[38 34 22 18 45 43 13 11]
[39 35 23 19 46 44 14 12]
[40 36 24 20 47 45 15 13]
[0 37 0 21 48 46 16 14]
[0 38 0 22 0 47 0 15]
[43 0 27 0 50 0 18 0]
[44 0 28 0 51 49 19 17]
[45 41 29 25 52 50 20 18]
[46 42 30 26 53 51 21 19]
[47 43 31 27 54 52 22 20]
[48 44 32 28 55 53 23 21]
[0 45 0 29 56 54 24 22]
[0 46 0 30 0 55 0 23]
[51 0 35 0 58 0 26 0]
[52 0 36 0 59 57 27 25]
[53 49 37 33 60 58 28 26]
[54 50 38 34 61 59 29 27]
[55 51 39 35 62 60 30 28]
[56 52 40 36 63 61 31 29]
[0 53 0 37 64 62 32 30]
[0 54 0 38 0 63 0 31]
[59 0 43 0 0 0 34 0]
[60 0 44 0 0 0 35 33]
[61 57 45 41 0 0 36 34]
[62 58 46 42 0 0 37 35]
[63 59 47 43 0 0 38 36]
[64 60 48 44 0 0 39 37]
[0 61 0 45 0 0 40 38]
[0 62 0 46 0 0 0 39]
[0 0 51 0 0 0 42 0]
[0 0 52 0 0 0 43 41]
[0 0 53 49 0 0 44 42]
[0 0 54 50 0 0 45 43]
[0 0 55 51 0 0 46 44]
[0 0 56 52 0 0 47 45]
[0 0 0 53 0 0 48 46]
[0 0 0 54 0 0 0 47]
```

Comment: Your request is unclear. Please reduce the lines of example, and instead add information about what you tried, and what you expect.

Comment: The Tour of Go is a really helpful resource on how to do various things in Go. Why not work through once more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple array:

```golang
a8 := [8]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
fmt.Println(a8) // [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Also:

```golang
a8 := [8]int{}
fmt.Println(a8) // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

This is called array of array:

```golang
b := [64][8]int{}
for i, v := range b {
    for j, _ := range v {
        b[i][j] = i*100 + j
    }
    fmt.Println(b[i])
}
```

Demonstration working sample Code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    aa := [64][8]int{}
    fmt.Println(aa)

    for i, v := range a {
        for j, w := range v {
            fmt.Println("a[", i, "]", "[", j, "]=", a[i][j], "=", w)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println()

    for _, v := range a {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

var a = [64][8]int{[8]int{11, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0},
    [8]int{12, 0, 0, 0, 19, 17, 0, 0},
    [8]int{13, 9, 0, 0, 20, 18, 0, 0},
    [8]int{14, 10, 0, 0, 21, 19, 0, 0},
    [8]int{15, 11, 0, 0, 22, 20, 0, 0},
    [8]int{16, 12, 0, 0, 23, 21, 0, 0},
    [8]int{0, 13, 0, 0, 24, 22, 0, 0},
    [8]int{0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0},
    [8]int{19, 0, 3, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0},
    [8]int{20, 0, 4, 0, 27, 25, 0, 0},
    [8]int{21, 17, 5, 1, 28, 26, 0, 0},
    [8]int{22, 18, 6, 2, 29, 27, 0, 0},
    [8]int{23, 19, 7, 3, 30, 28, 0, 0},
    [8]int{24, 20, 8, 4, 31, 29, 0, 0},
    [8]int{0, 21, 0, 5, 32, 30, 0, 0},
    [8]int{0, 22, 0, 6, 0, 31, 0, 0},
    [8]int{27, 0, 11, 0, 34, 0, 2, 0},
    [8]int{28, 0, 12, 0, 35, 33, 3, 1},
    [8]int{29, 25, 13, 9, 36, 34, 4, 2},
    [8]int{30, 26, 14, 10, 37, 35, 5, 3},
    [8]int{31, 27, 15, 11, 38, 36, 6, 4},
    [8]int{32, 28, 16, 12, 39, 37, 7, 5},
    [8]int{0, 29, 0, 13, 40, 38, 8, 6},
    [8]int{0, 30, 0, 14, 0, 39, 0, 7},
    [8]int{35, 0, 19, 0, 42, 0, 10, 0},
    [8]int{36, 0, 20, 0, 43, 41, 11, 9},
    [8]int{37, 33, 21, 17, 44, 42, 12, 10},
    [8]int{38, 34, 22, 18, 45, 43, 13, 11},
    [8]int{39, 35, 23, 19, 46, 44, 14, 12},
    [8]int{40, 36, 24, 20, 47, 45, 15, 13},
    [8]int{0, 37, 0, 21, 48, 46, 16, 14},
    [8]int{0, 38, 0, 22, 0, 47, 0, 15},
    [8]int{43, 0, 27, 0, 50, 0, 18, 0},
    [8]int{44, 0, 28, 0, 51, 49, 19, 17},
    [8]int{45, 41, 29, 25, 52, 50, 20, 18},
    [8]int{46, 42, 30, 26, 53, 51, 21, 19},
    [8]int{47, 43, 31, 27, 54, 52, 22, 20},
    [8]int{48, 44, 32, 28, 55, 53, 23, 21},
    [8]int{0, 45, 0, 29, 56, 54, 24, 22},
    [8]int{0, 46, 0, 30, 0, 55, 0, 23},
    [8]int{51, 0, 35, 0, 58, 0, 26, 0},
    [8]int{52, 0, 36, 0, 59, 57, 27, 25},
    [8]int{53, 49, 37, 33, 60, 58, 28, 26},
    [8]int{54, 50, 38, 34, 61, 59, 29, 27},
    [8]int{55, 51, 39, 35, 62, 60, 30, 28},
    [8]int{56, 52, 40, 36, 63, 61, 31, 29},
    [8]int{0, 53, 0, 37, 64, 62, 32, 30},
    [8]int{0, 54, 0, 38, 0, 63, 0, 31},
    [8]int{59, 0, 43, 0, 0, 0, 34, 0},
    [8]int{60, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 35, 33},
    [8]int{61, 57, 45, 41, 0, 0, 36, 34},
    [8]int{62, 58, 46, 42, 0, 0, 37, 35},
    [8]int{63, 59, 47, 43, 0, 0, 38, 36},
    [8]int{64, 60, 48, 44, 0, 0, 39, 37},
    [8]int{0, 61, 0, 45, 0, 0, 40, 38},
    [8]int{0, 62, 0, 46, 0, 0, 0, 39},
    [8]int{0, 0, 51, 0, 0, 0, 42, 0},
    [8]int{0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 43, 41},
    [8]int{0, 0, 53, 49, 0, 0, 44, 42},
    [8]int{0, 0, 54, 50, 0, 0, 45, 43},
    [8]int{0, 0, 55, 51, 0, 0, 46, 44},
    [8]int{0, 0, 56, 52, 0, 0, 47, 45},
    [8]int{0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0, 48, 46},
    [8]int{0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0, 47},
}
```

output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
a[ 0 ] [ 0 ]= 11 = 11
a[ 0 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 0 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 0 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 0 ] [ 4 ]= 18 = 18
a[ 0 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 0 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 0 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 1 ] [ 0 ]= 12 = 12
a[ 1 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 1 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 1 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 1 ] [ 4 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 1 ] [ 5 ]= 17 = 17
a[ 1 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 1 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 2 ] [ 0 ]= 13 = 13
a[ 2 ] [ 1 ]= 9 = 9
a[ 2 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 2 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 2 ] [ 4 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 2 ] [ 5 ]= 18 = 18
a[ 2 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 2 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 3 ] [ 0 ]= 14 = 14
a[ 3 ] [ 1 ]= 10 = 10
a[ 3 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 3 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 3 ] [ 4 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 3 ] [ 5 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 3 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 3 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 4 ] [ 0 ]= 15 = 15
a[ 4 ] [ 1 ]= 11 = 11
a[ 4 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 4 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 4 ] [ 4 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 4 ] [ 5 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 4 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 4 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 5 ] [ 0 ]= 16 = 16
a[ 5 ] [ 1 ]= 12 = 12
a[ 5 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 5 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 5 ] [ 4 ]= 23 = 23
a[ 5 ] [ 5 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 5 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 5 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 6 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 6 ] [ 1 ]= 13 = 13
a[ 6 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 6 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 6 ] [ 4 ]= 24 = 24
a[ 6 ] [ 5 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 6 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 6 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 7 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 7 ] [ 1 ]= 14 = 14
a[ 7 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 7 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 7 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 7 ] [ 5 ]= 23 = 23
a[ 7 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 7 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 8 ] [ 0 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 8 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 8 ] [ 2 ]= 3 = 3
a[ 8 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 8 ] [ 4 ]= 26 = 26
a[ 8 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 8 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 8 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 9 ] [ 0 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 9 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 9 ] [ 2 ]= 4 = 4
a[ 9 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 9 ] [ 4 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 9 ] [ 5 ]= 25 = 25
a[ 9 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 9 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 10 ] [ 0 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 10 ] [ 1 ]= 17 = 17
a[ 10 ] [ 2 ]= 5 = 5
a[ 10 ] [ 3 ]= 1 = 1
a[ 10 ] [ 4 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 10 ] [ 5 ]= 26 = 26
a[ 10 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 10 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 11 ] [ 0 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 11 ] [ 1 ]= 18 = 18
a[ 11 ] [ 2 ]= 6 = 6
a[ 11 ] [ 3 ]= 2 = 2
a[ 11 ] [ 4 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 11 ] [ 5 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 11 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 11 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 12 ] [ 0 ]= 23 = 23
a[ 12 ] [ 1 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 12 ] [ 2 ]= 7 = 7
a[ 12 ] [ 3 ]= 3 = 3
a[ 12 ] [ 4 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 12 ] [ 5 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 12 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 12 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 13 ] [ 0 ]= 24 = 24
a[ 13 ] [ 1 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 13 ] [ 2 ]= 8 = 8
a[ 13 ] [ 3 ]= 4 = 4
a[ 13 ] [ 4 ]= 31 = 31
a[ 13 ] [ 5 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 13 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 13 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 14 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 14 ] [ 1 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 14 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 14 ] [ 3 ]= 5 = 5
a[ 14 ] [ 4 ]= 32 = 32
a[ 14 ] [ 5 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 14 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 14 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 15 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 15 ] [ 1 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 15 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 15 ] [ 3 ]= 6 = 6
a[ 15 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 15 ] [ 5 ]= 31 = 31
a[ 15 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 15 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 16 ] [ 0 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 16 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 16 ] [ 2 ]= 11 = 11
a[ 16 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 16 ] [ 4 ]= 34 = 34
a[ 16 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 16 ] [ 6 ]= 2 = 2
a[ 16 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 17 ] [ 0 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 17 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 17 ] [ 2 ]= 12 = 12
a[ 17 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 17 ] [ 4 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 17 ] [ 5 ]= 33 = 33
a[ 17 ] [ 6 ]= 3 = 3
a[ 17 ] [ 7 ]= 1 = 1
a[ 18 ] [ 0 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 18 ] [ 1 ]= 25 = 25
a[ 18 ] [ 2 ]= 13 = 13
a[ 18 ] [ 3 ]= 9 = 9
a[ 18 ] [ 4 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 18 ] [ 5 ]= 34 = 34
a[ 18 ] [ 6 ]= 4 = 4
a[ 18 ] [ 7 ]= 2 = 2
a[ 19 ] [ 0 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 19 ] [ 1 ]= 26 = 26
a[ 19 ] [ 2 ]= 14 = 14
a[ 19 ] [ 3 ]= 10 = 10
a[ 19 ] [ 4 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 19 ] [ 5 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 19 ] [ 6 ]= 5 = 5
a[ 19 ] [ 7 ]= 3 = 3
a[ 20 ] [ 0 ]= 31 = 31
a[ 20 ] [ 1 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 20 ] [ 2 ]= 15 = 15
a[ 20 ] [ 3 ]= 11 = 11
a[ 20 ] [ 4 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 20 ] [ 5 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 20 ] [ 6 ]= 6 = 6
a[ 20 ] [ 7 ]= 4 = 4
a[ 21 ] [ 0 ]= 32 = 32
a[ 21 ] [ 1 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 21 ] [ 2 ]= 16 = 16
a[ 21 ] [ 3 ]= 12 = 12
a[ 21 ] [ 4 ]= 39 = 39
a[ 21 ] [ 5 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 21 ] [ 6 ]= 7 = 7
a[ 21 ] [ 7 ]= 5 = 5
a[ 22 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 22 ] [ 1 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 22 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 22 ] [ 3 ]= 13 = 13
a[ 22 ] [ 4 ]= 40 = 40
a[ 22 ] [ 5 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 22 ] [ 6 ]= 8 = 8
a[ 22 ] [ 7 ]= 6 = 6
a[ 23 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 23 ] [ 1 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 23 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 23 ] [ 3 ]= 14 = 14
a[ 23 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 23 ] [ 5 ]= 39 = 39
a[ 23 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 23 ] [ 7 ]= 7 = 7
a[ 24 ] [ 0 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 24 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 24 ] [ 2 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 24 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 24 ] [ 4 ]= 42 = 42
a[ 24 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 24 ] [ 6 ]= 10 = 10
a[ 24 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 25 ] [ 0 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 25 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 25 ] [ 2 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 25 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 25 ] [ 4 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 25 ] [ 5 ]= 41 = 41
a[ 25 ] [ 6 ]= 11 = 11
a[ 25 ] [ 7 ]= 9 = 9
a[ 26 ] [ 0 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 26 ] [ 1 ]= 33 = 33
a[ 26 ] [ 2 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 26 ] [ 3 ]= 17 = 17
a[ 26 ] [ 4 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 26 ] [ 5 ]= 42 = 42
a[ 26 ] [ 6 ]= 12 = 12
a[ 26 ] [ 7 ]= 10 = 10
a[ 27 ] [ 0 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 27 ] [ 1 ]= 34 = 34
a[ 27 ] [ 2 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 27 ] [ 3 ]= 18 = 18
a[ 27 ] [ 4 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 27 ] [ 5 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 27 ] [ 6 ]= 13 = 13
a[ 27 ] [ 7 ]= 11 = 11
a[ 28 ] [ 0 ]= 39 = 39
a[ 28 ] [ 1 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 28 ] [ 2 ]= 23 = 23
a[ 28 ] [ 3 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 28 ] [ 4 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 28 ] [ 5 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 28 ] [ 6 ]= 14 = 14
a[ 28 ] [ 7 ]= 12 = 12
a[ 29 ] [ 0 ]= 40 = 40
a[ 29 ] [ 1 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 29 ] [ 2 ]= 24 = 24
a[ 29 ] [ 3 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 29 ] [ 4 ]= 47 = 47
a[ 29 ] [ 5 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 29 ] [ 6 ]= 15 = 15
a[ 29 ] [ 7 ]= 13 = 13
a[ 30 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 30 ] [ 1 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 30 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 30 ] [ 3 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 30 ] [ 4 ]= 48 = 48
a[ 30 ] [ 5 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 30 ] [ 6 ]= 16 = 16
a[ 30 ] [ 7 ]= 14 = 14
a[ 31 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 31 ] [ 1 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 31 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 31 ] [ 3 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 31 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 31 ] [ 5 ]= 47 = 47
a[ 31 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 31 ] [ 7 ]= 15 = 15
a[ 32 ] [ 0 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 32 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 32 ] [ 2 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 32 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 32 ] [ 4 ]= 50 = 50
a[ 32 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 32 ] [ 6 ]= 18 = 18
a[ 32 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 33 ] [ 0 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 33 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 33 ] [ 2 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 33 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 33 ] [ 4 ]= 51 = 51
a[ 33 ] [ 5 ]= 49 = 49
a[ 33 ] [ 6 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 33 ] [ 7 ]= 17 = 17
a[ 34 ] [ 0 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 34 ] [ 1 ]= 41 = 41
a[ 34 ] [ 2 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 34 ] [ 3 ]= 25 = 25
a[ 34 ] [ 4 ]= 52 = 52
a[ 34 ] [ 5 ]= 50 = 50
a[ 34 ] [ 6 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 34 ] [ 7 ]= 18 = 18
a[ 35 ] [ 0 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 35 ] [ 1 ]= 42 = 42
a[ 35 ] [ 2 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 35 ] [ 3 ]= 26 = 26
a[ 35 ] [ 4 ]= 53 = 53
a[ 35 ] [ 5 ]= 51 = 51
a[ 35 ] [ 6 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 35 ] [ 7 ]= 19 = 19
a[ 36 ] [ 0 ]= 47 = 47
a[ 36 ] [ 1 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 36 ] [ 2 ]= 31 = 31
a[ 36 ] [ 3 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 36 ] [ 4 ]= 54 = 54
a[ 36 ] [ 5 ]= 52 = 52
a[ 36 ] [ 6 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 36 ] [ 7 ]= 20 = 20
a[ 37 ] [ 0 ]= 48 = 48
a[ 37 ] [ 1 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 37 ] [ 2 ]= 32 = 32
a[ 37 ] [ 3 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 37 ] [ 4 ]= 55 = 55
a[ 37 ] [ 5 ]= 53 = 53
a[ 37 ] [ 6 ]= 23 = 23
a[ 37 ] [ 7 ]= 21 = 21
a[ 38 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 38 ] [ 1 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 38 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 38 ] [ 3 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 38 ] [ 4 ]= 56 = 56
a[ 38 ] [ 5 ]= 54 = 54
a[ 38 ] [ 6 ]= 24 = 24
a[ 38 ] [ 7 ]= 22 = 22
a[ 39 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 39 ] [ 1 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 39 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 39 ] [ 3 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 39 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 39 ] [ 5 ]= 55 = 55
a[ 39 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 39 ] [ 7 ]= 23 = 23
a[ 40 ] [ 0 ]= 51 = 51
a[ 40 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 40 ] [ 2 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 40 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 40 ] [ 4 ]= 58 = 58
a[ 40 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 40 ] [ 6 ]= 26 = 26
a[ 40 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 41 ] [ 0 ]= 52 = 52
a[ 41 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 41 ] [ 2 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 41 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 41 ] [ 4 ]= 59 = 59
a[ 41 ] [ 5 ]= 57 = 57
a[ 41 ] [ 6 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 41 ] [ 7 ]= 25 = 25
a[ 42 ] [ 0 ]= 53 = 53
a[ 42 ] [ 1 ]= 49 = 49
a[ 42 ] [ 2 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 42 ] [ 3 ]= 33 = 33
a[ 42 ] [ 4 ]= 60 = 60
a[ 42 ] [ 5 ]= 58 = 58
a[ 42 ] [ 6 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 42 ] [ 7 ]= 26 = 26
a[ 43 ] [ 0 ]= 54 = 54
a[ 43 ] [ 1 ]= 50 = 50
a[ 43 ] [ 2 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 43 ] [ 3 ]= 34 = 34
a[ 43 ] [ 4 ]= 61 = 61
a[ 43 ] [ 5 ]= 59 = 59
a[ 43 ] [ 6 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 43 ] [ 7 ]= 27 = 27
a[ 44 ] [ 0 ]= 55 = 55
a[ 44 ] [ 1 ]= 51 = 51
a[ 44 ] [ 2 ]= 39 = 39
a[ 44 ] [ 3 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 44 ] [ 4 ]= 62 = 62
a[ 44 ] [ 5 ]= 60 = 60
a[ 44 ] [ 6 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 44 ] [ 7 ]= 28 = 28
a[ 45 ] [ 0 ]= 56 = 56
a[ 45 ] [ 1 ]= 52 = 52
a[ 45 ] [ 2 ]= 40 = 40
a[ 45 ] [ 3 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 45 ] [ 4 ]= 63 = 63
a[ 45 ] [ 5 ]= 61 = 61
a[ 45 ] [ 6 ]= 31 = 31
a[ 45 ] [ 7 ]= 29 = 29
a[ 46 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 46 ] [ 1 ]= 53 = 53
a[ 46 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 46 ] [ 3 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 46 ] [ 4 ]= 64 = 64
a[ 46 ] [ 5 ]= 62 = 62
a[ 46 ] [ 6 ]= 32 = 32
a[ 46 ] [ 7 ]= 30 = 30
a[ 47 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 47 ] [ 1 ]= 54 = 54
a[ 47 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 47 ] [ 3 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 47 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 47 ] [ 5 ]= 63 = 63
a[ 47 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 47 ] [ 7 ]= 31 = 31
a[ 48 ] [ 0 ]= 59 = 59
a[ 48 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 48 ] [ 2 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 48 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 48 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 48 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 48 ] [ 6 ]= 34 = 34
a[ 48 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 49 ] [ 0 ]= 60 = 60
a[ 49 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 49 ] [ 2 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 49 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 49 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 49 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 49 ] [ 6 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 49 ] [ 7 ]= 33 = 33
a[ 50 ] [ 0 ]= 61 = 61
a[ 50 ] [ 1 ]= 57 = 57
a[ 50 ] [ 2 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 50 ] [ 3 ]= 41 = 41
a[ 50 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 50 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 50 ] [ 6 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 50 ] [ 7 ]= 34 = 34
a[ 51 ] [ 0 ]= 62 = 62
a[ 51 ] [ 1 ]= 58 = 58
a[ 51 ] [ 2 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 51 ] [ 3 ]= 42 = 42
a[ 51 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 51 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 51 ] [ 6 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 51 ] [ 7 ]= 35 = 35
a[ 52 ] [ 0 ]= 63 = 63
a[ 52 ] [ 1 ]= 59 = 59
a[ 52 ] [ 2 ]= 47 = 47
a[ 52 ] [ 3 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 52 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 52 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 52 ] [ 6 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 52 ] [ 7 ]= 36 = 36
a[ 53 ] [ 0 ]= 64 = 64
a[ 53 ] [ 1 ]= 60 = 60
a[ 53 ] [ 2 ]= 48 = 48
a[ 53 ] [ 3 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 53 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 53 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 53 ] [ 6 ]= 39 = 39
a[ 53 ] [ 7 ]= 37 = 37
a[ 54 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 54 ] [ 1 ]= 61 = 61
a[ 54 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 54 ] [ 3 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 54 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 54 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 54 ] [ 6 ]= 40 = 40
a[ 54 ] [ 7 ]= 38 = 38
a[ 55 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 55 ] [ 1 ]= 62 = 62
a[ 55 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 55 ] [ 3 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 55 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 55 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 55 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 55 ] [ 7 ]= 39 = 39
a[ 56 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 56 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 56 ] [ 2 ]= 51 = 51
a[ 56 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 56 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 56 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 56 ] [ 6 ]= 42 = 42
a[ 56 ] [ 7 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 57 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 57 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 57 ] [ 2 ]= 52 = 52
a[ 57 ] [ 3 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 57 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 57 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 57 ] [ 6 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 57 ] [ 7 ]= 41 = 41
a[ 58 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 58 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 58 ] [ 2 ]= 53 = 53
a[ 58 ] [ 3 ]= 49 = 49
a[ 58 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 58 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 58 ] [ 6 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 58 ] [ 7 ]= 42 = 42
a[ 59 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 59 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 59 ] [ 2 ]= 54 = 54
a[ 59 ] [ 3 ]= 50 = 50
a[ 59 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 59 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 59 ] [ 6 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 59 ] [ 7 ]= 43 = 43
a[ 60 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 60 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 60 ] [ 2 ]= 55 = 55
a[ 60 ] [ 3 ]= 51 = 51
a[ 60 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 60 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 60 ] [ 6 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 60 ] [ 7 ]= 44 = 44
a[ 61 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 61 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 61 ] [ 2 ]= 56 = 56
a[ 61 ] [ 3 ]= 52 = 52
a[ 61 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 61 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 61 ] [ 6 ]= 47 = 47
a[ 61 ] [ 7 ]= 45 = 45
a[ 62 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 62 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 62 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 62 ] [ 3 ]= 53 = 53
a[ 62 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 62 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 62 ] [ 6 ]= 48 = 48
a[ 62 ] [ 7 ]= 46 = 46
a[ 63 ] [ 0 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 63 ] [ 1 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 63 ] [ 2 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 63 ] [ 3 ]= 54 = 54
a[ 63 ] [ 4 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 63 ] [ 5 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 63 ] [ 6 ]= 0 = 0
a[ 63 ] [ 7 ]= 47 = 47

[11 0 0 0 18 0 0 0]
[12 0 0 0 19 17 0 0]
[13 9 0 0 20 18 0 0]
[14 10 0 0 21 19 0 0]
[15 11 0 0 22 20 0 0]
[16 12 0 0 23 21 0 0]
[0 13 0 0 24 22 0 0]
[0 14 0 0 0 23 0 0]
[19 0 3 0 26 0 0 0]
[20 0 4 0 27 25 0 0]
[21 17 5 1 28 26 0 0]
[22 18 6 2 29 27 0 0]
[23 19 7 3 30 28 0 0]
[24 20 8 4 31 29 0 0]
[0 21 0 5 32 30 0 0]
[0 22 0 6 0 31 0 0]
[27 0 11 0 34 0 2 0]
[28 0 12 0 35 33 3 1]
[29 25 13 9 36 34 4 2]
[30 26 14 10 37 35 5 3]
[31 27 15 11 38 36 6 4]
[32 28 16 12 39 37 7 5]
[0 29 0 13 40 38 8 6]
[0 30 0 14 0 39 0 7]
[35 0 19 0 42 0 10 0]
[36 0 20 0 43 41 11 9]
[37 33 21 17 44 42 12 10]
[38 34 22 18 45 43 13 11]
[39 35 23 19 46 44 14 12]
[40 36 24 20 47 45 15 13]
[0 37 0 21 48 46 16 14]
[0 38 0 22 0 47 0 15]
[43 0 27 0 50 0 18 0]
[44 0 28 0 51 49 19 17]
[45 41 29 25 52 50 20 18]
[46 42 30 26 53 51 21 19]
[47 43 31 27 54 52 22 20]
[48 44 32 28 55 53 23 21]
[0 45 0 29 56 54 24 22]
[0 46 0 30 0 55 0 23]
[51 0 35 0 58 0 26 0]
[52 0 36 0 59 57 27 25]
[53 49 37 33 60 58 28 26]
[54 50 38 34 61 59 29 27]
[55 51 39 35 62 60 30 28]
[56 52 40 36 63 61 31 29]
[0 53 0 37 64 62 32 30]
[0 54 0 38 0 63 0 31]
[59 0 43 0 0 0 34 0]
[60 0 44 0 0 0 35 33]
[61 57 45 41 0 0 36 34]
[62 58 46 42 0 0 37 35]
[63 59 47 43 0 0 38 36]
[64 60 48 44 0 0 39 37]
[0 61 0 45 0 0 40 38]
[0 62 0 46 0 0 0 39]
[0 0 51 0 0 0 42 0]
[0 0 52 0 0 0 43 41]
[0 0 53 49 0 0 44 42]
[0 0 54 50 0 0 45 43]
[0 0 55 51 0 0 46 44]
[0 0 56 52 0 0 47 45]
[0 0 0 53 0 0 48 46]
[0 0 0 54 0 0 0 47]
```

Comment: Not exactly but with help of this I could do what i needed.Thanks